# PDF Tj command with angle brackets?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to figure out where in an *uncompressed* PDF v1.4 document the Times font is used.

The `/Font` object describing the Times font within the PDF is object `65` as follows:

```
65 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /TrueType
/BaseFont /PXAAAD+TimesNewRoman,Italic
/FirstChar 1
/LastChar 35
/Widths [250 333 333 333 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 333 722 722 833 666 610 500 556 500 443 443 500 277 443 500 389 389 277 500 443 500]
/FontDescriptor 205 0 R
/ToUnicode 206 0 R>>
endobj
```

It refers to a `/FontDescriptor` object `205` to further define the Times font object, and to a `/ToUnicode` map in object `206` which describes byte-to-unicode character mapping. **EDIT:** After [Ritsaert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246383/ritsaert-hornstra)'s initial answer to the question below, I'm adding the font's `/ToUnicode` object here, to provide the mentioned `CMap`.

```
206 0 obj
<</Length 208 0 R>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <FF>
endcodespacerange
35 beginbfchar
<01> <0020>
<02> <0028>
<03> <0029>
<04> <002d>
<05> <0030>
<06> <0031>
<07> <0032>
...
<23> <0101>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

endstream
endobj
```

I've now tracked down the use of the Times font object to a `/Page` object (one of many) like the following one which refers to font object `65` through the `/F4` reference in its page `/Resources`:

```
12 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 432 648]
/Contents 92 0 R
/Resources <</Font <</F1 62 0 R
/F3 64 0 R
/F4 65 0 R>>
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text]>>
/Group <</S /Transparency
/CS /DeviceRGB>>>>
endobj
```

The `/Contents` stream (object `92` in the PDF file) is then full of text objects (enclosed in `BT` and `ET`), none of which contains text, but instead they use angle brackets full of numbers. For example, here is the only reference to the Times font `/F4` whose use I'm trying to find:

```
92 0 obj
<</Length 93 0 R>>
stream
...
BT
0.5020 g
72.0000 615.1512 Td
/F4 12.0000 Tf
<0605> Tj
ET
...
endstream
endobj
```

But what do the angle brackets and the number `<0605>` refer to? A specific glyph in the font table? Looking at the [PDF reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf) and section 5.3.2 I can't find mention of the angle brackets.

**EDIT:** Given the above code and the accepted answer that `<0605>` is a hex encoding of text, the `<0605>` are the entries `<06>` and `<05>` in the `CMap` object `206` and thus map to unicodes `<0031>` and `<0030>` respectively. That means, the string `<0605>` refers to U+0031 (a "1") and to U+0030 (a "0"), such that the Times font is used for the string "10" on page object `12`.

Comment: *The `/Contents` stream  is then full of text objects (enclosed in `BT` and `ET`), none of which contains text, but instead they use angle brackets full of numbers.* - As @Ritsaert already explained, the numbers in the angle brackets **are** strings which merely happen to be written in hexadecimal form.

Comment: @mkl: Which sums up the question and the answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is going on here:

- in the content stream the `Tj` command is given the string `<0605>` to draw. a string in between `<>` is a **hex** string and hence the characters #6 and #5 are drawn. In 3.2.3 of the linked PDF reference is the notation explained.
- Just before the text draw command the font `F4` is selected using the `Tf` command.
- Given the resource fork of the page containing the font is referenced as object 65 revision 0. This font object is a subsetted Truetype font where glyphs 1..35 are defined. No `Encoding` is specified (thus `WinAnsiEncoding` is used). So the embedded subsetted font rearranged the characters in the font in a non standard manner (occurs quite often).

Now if you want to know how these glyph IDs are linked to Unicode characters: the font has a `ToUnicode` link where a stream contains a `CMAP` defining the mapping. This should be sufficient to convert the string to an Unicode string.

Comment: Actually I don't think your remark about WinAnsiEncoding is correct. From the PDF specification when talking about the value of /Encoding in a font dictionary for TrueType fonts: "A font that is used to display glyphs that do not use MacRomanEncoding or WinAnsiEncoding should not specify an Encoding entry". Which by itself is strange as the key is described as "Required" in the original description of the font dictionary. I would guess that the font indeed uses a fully proprietary encoding and thus it should also have the symbolic bit set in the font descriptor. Aren't fonts cool? :)

Comment: @David: for type1 fonts the default is StandardEncoding, for TT fonts WinAnsiEncoding. Fonts in PDf files are usually a horrible horrible mess and you need a lot of trickery / assumptions and the correct phase of the moon even to render these correctly (I build a PDF renderer and this part is the worst). If it is specified as a symbolic font the encoding should be 1on1 as you described. Almost all PDFs out there contain errors in them (invalid entries, invalid names, names instead of strings or vise versa. PDF readers are truly magnificent beasts, the shear amount of crap they can parse...

Comment: I also wrote (part of) a PDF renderer :-) but I think I escaped most of the font stuff; so you're saying that while the PDF specification might state the encoding is required for TrueType fonts, that actually isn't followed correctly in the field? Or did I miss part of the PDF spec where this default is defined? That's quite interesting actually (which says something about me I guess :))

Comment: @RitsaertHornstra: I've edited the question to add the mentioned `CMap`. If I understand you correctly, the `<0605>` are entries `<06>` and `<05>` in that `CMap` object, which map to `<0031>` and `<0030>` respectively. That means, they refer to U+0031 (a "1") and to U+0030 (a "0"). Is that correct? If so, then the Times font is used to render a string "10"?

Comment: @Jens: You got it correct! Please note that the ToUnicode CMAP is only for text processing apps and has nothing to do with the rendering. So if the CMAP is correctly the PDF content writes out 10 onto the rendering target.