# PDF How to get Font object with id not in cross reference table

Tags: pdf

Like in this discussion,
[Tj command with angle brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762705/pdf-tj-command-with-angle-brackets)

I'm faced with TJ operator where content is between angle brackets:

<00030037005200570044004F000300550048004600520051005100580056>Tj

the parent page gives the list of font object id's like this

Font /C2_0 39 0 R/T1_0 41 0 R/T1_1 43 0 R/T1_2 44 0 R

and for the object where the angle brackets string is, a Tf operator specifies that the font reference is C2_0

So from the font list, I know the C2 font object is 39

Ok, but now, what is the fastest way to access this 39 object that is embedded in a stream object having 16 as id. In this #16 object, there is the list of embedded objects

32 0 33 106 34 131 35 141 36 193 37 436 38 16720 39 16728 ....

So my quetion is how to get the 16 value, when I only know that the font object id 39 is not in the cross reference table? Do I have to parse all stream objects and read their stream object list to detect which one has the object 39?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you parse pdf files, you obviously start by parsing the cross reference tables/streams, don't you? And in them there is the information you're after...

Comment: The bottom line is that object 39 should be accessible from the cross reference stream  (stream of /Type /XRef as referenced by `startxref` in the trailer), as a type 2 entry.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes I got two cross tables, one recent and one previous, but the 39 object id is not in these cross tables. Both tables come from an Xref object, without trailer. The first cross table object is 13 and there are 19 objects (last one is 31), in second cross table, the first object is 0 and there are 8 objects, so last one is 7. So the 39 object is not is cross tables, it is in the stream object 16 that is flatedecode compressed. This object is in the cross table, but how to know that I have to look for object 39 in the object 16?

Comment: For sure you have to interpret the Xref stream. As dwarriing written: It is an entry with the type 2.

Comment: Do you mean about the Xref stream that contains the cross tables? I did that to get the two cross tables (the new one and previous one). My problem is that none of them gives an entry to the object 39 that is embedded in stream object 16. The 39 object is only referenced in object 16, so not visible outside

Comment: I used the solution to parse all objects and look inside thoose that have "Font" in their dictionary. All of them have FlateDecode compression! So I inflate their content and look if they contain the 39 object I'm looking for. There I got the 16 0 R reference. By chance, this object is in cross table, so easy to find it. I had to inflate it also, to find the Cmap for decoding the coded string...Now I'm able to export the content of my pdf file into an Excel sheet with the use of zlib dll